# sqlite in yii framework

Tags: sqlite, yii

I am following the [blog tutorials](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/start.design) of YII Framework to get insight to it.

This tutorial is using SQLITE for database. I have never use SQLITE before. I have being using MYSQL and SQL SERVER. For MYSQL I can use phpmyadmin to create database and table integrated in WAMP. Here, I am not getting idea how to create database and table in SQLITE for the blog tutorial in link. Is there any quick reference for it.

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference to use MySql here. Just configure your main config to use a mysql db and create the tables in it.

Answer (score 1):

On the [very next page](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.1/en/prototype.database) of the tutorial is the following tip:

*Tip: To execute SQL statements, we may use the **sqlite3** command line tool that can be found in the [SQLite official website](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html).*